# Spark web UI showing two stages for a job without any wide transformation

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to understand spark  - Jobs and Stages through web ui. I ran a simple code for word count. The file has 44 lines in total.

```
strings = spark.read.text("word.txt")
filtered = strings.filter(strings.value.contains("The"))
filtered.count()
```

I see there are no wide transformation, and there is only 1 action. So, the application should have only 1 stage job. However I see there is a shuffle operation after read  in the web UI. It shows its a 2 stage job.  I am not sure why is it ? Can anyone please help me here ?

[image: Added screenshot from UI]

Edit : Adding SQL Plan

```
== Parsed Logical Plan ==
Aggregate [count(1) AS count#5L]
+- AnalysisBarrier
      +- Filter Contains(value#0, The)
         +- Relation[value#0] text

== Analyzed Logical Plan ==
count: bigint
Aggregate [count(1) AS count#5L]
+- Filter Contains(value#0, The)
   +- Relation[value#0] text

== Optimized Logical Plan ==
Aggregate [count(1) AS count#5L]
+- Project
   +- Filter (isnotnull(value#0) && Contains(value#0, The))
      +- Relation[value#0] text

== Physical Plan ==
*(2) HashAggregate(keys=[], functions=[count(1)], output=[count#5L])
+- Exchange SinglePartition
   +- *(1) HashAggregate(keys=[], functions=[partial_count(1)], output=[count#8L])
      +- *(1) Project
         +- *(1) Filter (isnotnull(value#0) && Contains(value#0, The))
            +- *(1) FileScan text [value#0] Batched: false, Format: Text, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[hdfs://dev/user/rk/word.txt], PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(value), StringContains(value,The)], ReadSchema: struct<value:string>
```

Comment: Can you go to the SQL tab and copy the plan details?

Comment: I have added the plan details in the question. Please check.

Comment: Yeah, it's not an acutal shuffle. You can see in the Physical Plan, Spark does a partial count on each partition and then shuffles the intermediate results to one executor to complete the count.
It's just a norma Map-Reduce, and the second stage is the reducer